# Python Import cannot find shared object file (C++ extension)

Tags: python, c++, linux, c++17, strace

I'm creating a C++ extension module for Python3. Compilation of the setup.py file compiles just fine, but when I go to import my new module, I get

`ImportError: libMyLib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

this is the path to my .so: 
`/path/to/lib-cc7/libMyLib.so`

I've tried to import my libraries in the setup.py in different ways, I have tried setting and re-setting my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in the terminal as well as in my .bash_profile. I have tried setting the paths in sys.path.

When I run this code before the import statement:

```
print(os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")) 
print(os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH"))
```

I get the path to the correct library directory.

When I run strace the path to other .so's that I need show up, and I see it searching for `libMyLib.so`, but it just searches in what seems like all of the other directories and `/path/to/lib-cc7/`. In other library searches it checks `/path/to/lib-cc7/`.

I have sanity checked that the library is there about 5 times.

It seems like no matter what I do,

`import MyModule.MySubModule as SubModule`

always returns the same import error. Is there anything else that I haven't tried? Why does it seem like Python is looking in the wrong place for my .so?

EDIT 1:

This is what my setup.py (in essence) looks like:

```
Submodule1 = Extension('Module.Submodule1', sources=['Module/Submodule1/submod1.cpp'], language = C++, libraries=[..long list of libraries..],)

Submodule2 = Extension('Module.Submodule2', sources=['Module/Submodule2/submod2.cpp'], language = C++, libraries=[..long list of libraries..],)

setup(name = "Module", version = '1.0', 
      packages = ['Module', 'Module.Submodule1', 'Module.Submodule2'],
      ext_modules = [Submodule1, Submodule2], )
```

Comment: What does your `setup.py` look like? Specifically I'm interested in the parameters `packages` and `include_package_data`. I've only ever gotten this error when those two parameters were incorrect, thereby putting the `.so` files in the wrong place (or not including them in the package at all).

Comment: @Eqomatic edit has been made